# StackExchange.Redis string value is converted to set

Tags: c#, .net, azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

I use StackExchange.Redis to work with cache.
I have action which returns values from cache (if value exists)

```
public ActionResult GetCalculatorSalaries()
    {
        var s = (string) _cache.StringGet("CalculatorSalaries");
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            var salaries = _service.LoadCalculatorSalaries();
            _cache.SetAdd("CalculatorSalaries", (string)salaries);
            return Json(salaries, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(s, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

`_service.LoadCalculatorSalaries();` - this is service which returns data from Azure Blob and here returns data as `string`.

Problem: I set value for key "CalculatorSalaries" as `string` but when i try to get it, i get an `error`, as value by that key is of type `set`.

Where i am wrong?

---

P.S. When i debug code at step

`var s = (string) _cache.StringGet("CalculatorSalaries");`

debuging skiping when value exists for key "CalculatorSalaries" and error get only in browser console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `SetAdd`... thereby adding a set.

Perhaps you meant `StringSet`:

```
var salaries = _service.LoadCalculatorSalaries();
_cache.StringSet("CalculatorSalaries", (string)salaries);
//     ^^^^^^^^^ this
```